# Fail tests by default (Intellij IDEA)

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit4

In NetBeans, when a new test is created, it fails by default by using something like `fail("Not tested yet.")` in the test method.

Is it possible to have similar behavior in Intellij IDEA?

Intellij IDEA creates empty methods, which pass by default. I want that all the created methods must fail, and then I can make them pass one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the template for the generated method in `Preferences | Editor | File and Code Templates`. Under the Code tab, look for *JUnit4 Test Method*, *JUnit5 Test Method* or *TestNG Test Method* depending on your the test framework you are using.